# Keeping a string variable from being destructured

Tags: clojure

Pretty simple question here, but it is really stumping me up.

I have a small function here:

```
(defn something
  [start-url n]
  (loop [urls start-url index n]                                 
    (if (= index 0)
      (set urls)
      (recur
        (flatten (pmap #(str *base-url* %) urls))
         (dec index)))))
```

I have changed the important parts of the code, but it basically just needs to map over a list of strings, and recur. However, when I start the loop, urls naturally destructures start-string into a list of chars, which I don't want.

At the same time, if I do

```
(loop [urls '(start-url) index n]
```

it unsurprisingly returns the seq with an unevaluated start-urls.

All I want to do is take my start-url and keep it as a string. Any ideas? It must be really simple, but alas, it is escaping me.

Comment: Is `start-url` one url or a collection of them?

Comment: I'm calling the function with one url, but I'd like to start the loop with it as a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `(loop [urls [start-url] index n] ...` should make `urls` into a vector containing the single string `start-url`, without the destructuring.

The reason `'(start-url)` doesn't do the same is that the quote applies to the whole structure, including `start-url`. `(list start-url)` should work, but a vector is typically preferable in this situation.

Comment: haha I did `(vec start-url)` even... ah so close. But yes this is what I needed thanks! It makes sense.